How to serialize a Variant Enum using borshjs
I am trying to create a Rust program on Solana without Anchor framework so I can figure out some details of Solana program. I have a Variant Enum in Rust like this:
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub enum TokenInstruction {
  InitializeMint,
  Mint { amount: u64 },
  Transfer { amount: u64 },
  Balance,
}

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
  program_id: &Pubkey,
  accounts: &[AccountInfo],
  instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
  let instruction = TokenInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)
      .map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;

  match instruction {
    TokenInstruction::InitializeMint => {
      initialize_mint(program_id, accounts)
    },
    TokenInstruction::Mint { amount } => {
      mint_tokens(program_id, accounts, amount)
    },
    TokenInstruction::Transfer { amount } => {
      transfer_tokens(program_id, accounts, amount)
    },
    TokenInstruction::Balance => {
      get_balance(program_id, accounts)
    }
  }
}

TokenInstruction is a Variant enum, like Mint and Transfer, each with additional fields. Here is my problem: how can I provide instruction_data in Node.js?
In @solana/web3.js there is a Enum class, but it seems like no not support Variant fields, I don't know what to do now, please help, thank you so much

const InitializeMintSchema = { 
  struct: 
    { 
      id: 'u8', 
    }
};
const MintSchema = {
  struct:
    {
      id: 'u8', 
      amount: 'u64',
   }
};
const initData = borsh.serialize(InitializeMintSchema, new InitializeMint({ id: 0 }));
....
const mintData = borsh.serialize(MintSchema, new Mint({ id: 1, amount: 100 }));

I have tried with above code, the initData works but mintData failed.
